# Different actions wanna perform on a common component

Tags: javascript, arrays, next.js, components

Having a grid component but I am facing difficulty to call their actions for different pages.
I made it work through router but that jump page and get that action and than return back to the same page. Is there any way I can do without router in next js?

Here is my code:

```
const handleActions = (btnPress, row) => {
    if (btnPress === "Add") router.push(`/admin/${actions}/[id]`, `/admin/${actions}/add`);
    else if (btnPress === "Edit") router.push(`/admin/${actions}/[id]`, `/admin/${actions}/${row.original._id}`)
    else if (btnPress === "Delete") router.push(`/admin/${actions}`, `/admin/${actions}/${row.original._id}`)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved through page useState by passing and updating state in component.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).